# What are the automatic rules make is using to build objects files without being specified?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have an old project with several C++ source and header files in a directory which are built in cygwin using GCC and a makefile. On editing the makefile to move all the temporary and output files into a sub-directory, the rules to build the object files didnt have any effect.

```
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $^

%.o: %.c
    $(CXX) $(INC) $(CXXFLAGS) $@ -c -o $<
```

The following makefile still builds the output binary without having any rules to build the object files from source code.

```
INC=-I.
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -O2 -g
LDFLAGS=
CLEAN_FILES=*.o *.out *.stackdump *.exe *.gcno *.gcda
BIN=app
SRC=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ=$(SRC:%.cpp=%.o)

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(CLEAN_FILES)
```

What is this automatic behavior called?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of rules that make knows about without you having to define them are called [*built-in rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html).  The manual lists most of them but not all of them.  You can run `make -p -f/dev/null` to see a list of them all.

Answer (score 3):

Two notes regarding built-in rules:

In large projects (which will have their owner rules for compiling, linking, ....), it might be easier to start with no built-in rules (`make -r` or `make --no-builtin-rules`).

Many built-in rules have hooks, via variables, that allow configuration changes. For example:

```
%.o: %.c:
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

...
COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
```

Where opssible to customize the command by modifying "CFLAGS", "CPPFLAGS", etc. Common examples will be `make "CFLAGS=-O -g"` to get optimized debug program, without having to redefine all the rules.